# What does sudo install -t mean?

Tags: 18.04, debian

On the website https://docs.drone.io/runner/exec/installation/linux/, there is a installation guide:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/drone-runners/drone-runner-exec/releases/latest/download/drone_runner_exec_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar zx
$ sudo install -t /usr/local/bin drone-runner-exec
```

and I would like to ask, what does `sudo install -t` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for `install` is pretty instructive:

`-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY`

`copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY`

Take a look: [`man install`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/install.1.html)